# Estancado en este código java arraylist de objetos

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

Estoy intentando aprender a programar en Java desde casa, y he encontrado un set de ejercicios, pero hay uno, el último que se me escapa, entiendo lo que hace el código, pero no lo que pide en el enunciado. Podría alguien resolverlo y explicarme un poco por encima.

Saludos.

El enunciado incluye estas piezas de código:

```
package unPaquete;

public class A {
    int id;
    public A(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public double m1() {
        double a = Math.random();
        double b = Math.random();
        return a - b * (id + Math.sqrt(a));
    }
}
```

---

```
package unPaquete;

public class B {
    int id;
    public B(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public double m1() {
        double a = Math.sin(Math.PI/Math.random());
        double b = Math.cos(Math.PI/Math.random());
        return a / b * (id + Math.pow(a, 5));
    }
}
```

---

```
package unPaquete;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ces {
    // Atributos.
    ArrayList<Object> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // Métodos.
    public void annadir(Object objeto) {
        lista.add(objeto);
    }
    
    public double suma() {
        double suma = 0;
        for(Object objeto : lista) {
            if(objeto instanceof A) {
                suma = ((A) objeto).m1();
            }else if(objeto instanceof B) {
                suma = ((B) objeto).m1();
            }
        }
        return suma;
    }
}
```

Y el enunciado dice:

> Se pide:
>
> - a) Modificar, basándose en los mecanismos de herencia y polimorfismo, el código para que no haya ninguna estructura de control dentro del bucle for del método suma de la clase Ces.
>   El comportamiento del código resultante debe ser igual que el del código proporcionado en
>   el enunciado, salvo que el nuevo código sólo admitirá como elementos de la lista de Ces
>   objetos construidos como de la clase A o como de la clase B.
> - b) Sobre el resultado del apartado anterior, implementar en la clase Ces el método borrar, que toma como entrada un elemento y lo borra de la lista. Para ello, debe modificar otra(s) clase(s) para que el borrado sea asumiendo que dos elementos son iguales si comparten el mismo valor para el atributo id.
>   En caso de que no haya logrado resolver el apartado anterior, puede resolver éste directamente sobre el código del enunciado.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Te está pidiendo que modifiques `Ces`, para que no tenga ese `if` dentro del bucle `for` en el método `suma()`, para ello debes modificar las otras dos clases, haciendo uso de la herencia para que ambas puedan ser usadas indistintamente dentro de `suma()`. Al menos eso es lo que he entendido yo. Te invito a que intentas hacer los cambios necesarios para que esto funcione así, antes de que alguien te dé una respuesta con la solución. La mejor manera de aprender a programar por ti mismo, es romperte la cabeza un buen rato! Y si tienes algún error concreto, siempre podrás preguntar aquí!

Comment: Por cierto, esta pregunta no sigue las reglas de la comunidad (de hecho te invito a leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para entender cómo funciona SO). Aquí no hacemos trabajo por otros, debes ***investigar*** e ***intentar hacer algo***, y si tienes un ***error concreto*** podrás preguntar aquí. Para tutoriales y ayudas, tienes youtube y google, donde podrás encontrar una enorme cantidad de contenido gratuito (y de pago también) para ayudarte. Te invito a ver el curso de Java del canal *PildorasInformaticas* de youtube, es realmente extenso y sencillo de seguir. Y es con el que aprendí yo :)